# Grouping records by day in PHP/MySQL

Tags: mysql

This is a common issue that I can't find an elegant way to handle.

Database contains 5000 records. I need to show these records on a page, but they need to be sorted and grouped by day.

### 10/11/2009

record3456

record456

record456

### 10/12/2009

record345234

record3456

### 10/13/2009

### 10/14/2009

record81

record8324

record983

record834

### 10/15/2009

record918

...

etc. How can this be done in MySQL/PHP? What about Ruby? I can grab all records and then sort them and manipulate them manually with PHP but that's SLOW.

Comment: Is the example for `10/11/2009` correct?  You've got duplicates of `record456`

Answer (score 3):

Do a:

```
ORDER BY your_date_column
```

in the query. You'll probably have to do the grouping in PHP - just see if the data differs from the last row, if it does, print a header.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the example for `10/11/2009` is incorrect because of the duplicates, this is a standard pivot query.  It's called pivotting because you're wanting to change row to column data.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN x.df = '10/11/2009' THEN x.record_column ELSE NULL END '10/11/2009',
       CASE WHEN x.df = '10/12/2009' THEN x.record_column ELSE NULL END '10/12/2009',
       CASE WHEN x.df = '10/13/2009' THEN x.record_column ELSE NULL END '10/13/2009',
  FROM (SELECT t.date_column,
               DATE_FORMAT(t.date_column, '%m/%d/%Y') 'df'
               t.record_column
          FROM TABLE t
      GROUP BY t.date_column,t.record_column) x
```

The problem with this is that your resultset will look like:

```
10/11/2009  | 10/12/2009    | 10/13/2009
-----------------------------------------
record3456  | NULL          | NULL
record456   | NULL          | NULL
NULL        | record345234  | NULL
NULL        | record3456    | NULL
```

It might be more simple & direct to just use:

```
SELECT t.record_column '10/11/2009'
  FROM TABLE t
 WHERE t.date_column = '10/11/2009'
```

...to query the records you want, in separate queries.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT *

FROM TABLE
GROUP BY DAY(dateField)

ORDER BY DAY(dateField)

http://www.tizag.com/sqlTutorial/sqldate.php

Comment: The problem with grouping by day is that the value could be for any month, and the example has duplicates in it which rules out grouping because it will eliminate duplicates.