# Selecting records in groups by date - possible?

Tags: sql, mysql

I don't think there is an elegant way to do this, but here goes. Database contains 5000 records with timestamps of 2 years. I need to pull the records under each day of the year.

So it looks like..

09/09/2009 - record938, record2, record493

09/10/2009 - record260, record485, record610

...etc

I cannot use GROUP BY. There are duplicates and that's OK. I need to show them.

Is this possible? PHP/MySQL?

One way of doing it is looping through every day of the year and doing a query with "WHERE DAY(created_at)..." but obviously this isn't elegant.

HOW can I do this? I posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1806634/grouping-records-by-day-in-php-mysql) before without a satisfactory answer (answer was what I just stated above)

Comment: Can you explain why you cannot use `GROUP BY`?

Comment: @Adam: "There are duplicates and that's OK."

Comment: @OMG: But the *records* are what he wants duplicates of, not the *dates*, which is what would be the grouping statement. See intgr's answer for more detail.

Comment: @Adam: See the previous question - I'm more than aware of the situation Isdude is wanting to solve.

Comment: And can you please explain why `group_concat` does not solve his issue?

Comment: @OMG: The solution he presents is perfectly reasonable. I fail to see how it doesn't satisfy the requirements, *especially* in light of the format that is presented in this question (the other appears to use line breaks instead of commas).

Comment: @intgr: I'm not saying you're wrong - it looks right to me, but I don't have Isdude's data ;)

Answer (score 4):

MySQL has the [group_concat() aggregate function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
SELECT date(rec_time), group_concat(rec_id)
FROM records GROUP BY date(rec_time);
```

Will return all `rec_id` values from table joined by commas, for each date. If you want a separator other than `,` use `group_concat(some_column SEPARATOR '-')`

### Example

For example if your table looks like:

```
+--------+---------------------+
| rec_id | rec_time            |
+--------+---------------------+
|      1 | 2009-11-28 10:00:00 |
|      2 | 2009-11-28 20:00:00 |
|      3 | 2009-11-27 15:00:00 |
|      4 | 2009-11-27 07:00:00 |
|      5 | 2009-11-28 08:00:00 |
+--------+---------------------+
```

Then this query gives:

```
mysql> SELECT date(rec_time), group_concat(rec_id) 
    -> FROM records GROUP BY date(rec_time);
+----------------+----------------------+
| date(rec_time) | group_concat(rec_id) |
+----------------+----------------------+
| 2009-11-27     | 3,4                  |
| 2009-11-28     | 1,2,5                |
+----------------+----------------------+
```

### Caveat

Beware that the result is limited by the `group_concat_max_len` system variable, which defaults to only 1024 bytes! To avoid hitting this wall, you should execute this before running the query:

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 65536;
```

Or more, depending on how many results you expect. But this value *cannot* be larger than `max_allowed_packet`